# CSS Collapsable Sections

Tags: css

I am looking to a way to make a comment line, and use it to collapse everything under it until the next comment line or something similar, so I can group parts of the css code that belong to the same cathegory. I dont know if there is some option like that.

Sorry for the newbie question I just started to learn!

Comment: Unfortunately your question, as it stands, isn't a good fit for Stack Overflow's format. Questions here (see "[ask]") need to be specific programming problems, with illustrative, specific code samples and a clear description of the expectation of that code, and the problems that occur with it. As written your question seems to be asking us to help you brain-storm a potential solution, which is both opinion-based (and so off-topic) and, also, has insufficient means to determine an "objectively-correct" answer.

Comment: Sounds like [sass](https://sass-lang.com/) might be something you are looking for. Scss still has to be compiled though.

Comment: When do you want it to collapse, when you are in some specific editor or are you writing your own? As it stands your question lacks context.

Comment: Yes, I think David missunderstood my question. I am not looking for someone to write me any code, I just want to organize my own code.

I am using visual studio code, and I would like to collapse sections. I used to write C# code and there I would use regions, for something like that.

I guess a more clear way to ask it would be: Is there any equivalent of sections on CSS when using visual studio code? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Ok I keep searching and I found it. In CSS I can do:

```
/*#region*/
CODE HERE
/*#endregion*/
```

And that allows me to collapse the region section. Thats on visual studio code. Thanks for the help!